# Spring Integration Header Value Router Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am configuring a Header Value Router with a default channel output, but it seems that the following code is not properly wrote.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("defaultRouterChannel")
MessageChannel defaultRouterChannel; //PubSub channel

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow amqpFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("rabbitMqChannel")
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Agreement.class))
            .route(router())
            .get();
}


public HeaderValueRouter router() {
    HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter(AGREEMENT_HEADER);
    router.setDefaultOutputChannel(defaultRouteChannel);
    router.setChannelMapping("ENROLL", "enrollChannel");
    router.setChannelMapping("ENLIST", "enlistChannel");
    return router;
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow defaultRoute() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(defaultRouterChannel)
            .log()
            .get();
}
```

The documentation mention the following 
"Set the default channel where Messages should be sent if channel resolution fails to return any channels. If no default channel is provided and channel resolution fails to return any channels, the router will throw an MessageDeliveryException."

The problem is when is sent a valid "agreement header" "so far so good", but when i test the router with a "invalid header" it throws a "*MessageDeliveryException*"

as it follows.

Suppose that i send a header with value "LOCAL"

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'LOCAL'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'LOCAL' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'LOCAL' available
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addChannelFromString(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:258)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addToCollection(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:282)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.determineTargetChannels(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.access$000(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher$1.run(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:204)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

Spring Integration version 5.0.5

Kind Regards.

Comment: Not all configuration is being shown for a matter of simplicity;

Answer (score 0):

The documentation also says

> A Message will only be sent to the `default-output-channel` if `resolution-required` is `false` and the channel is not resolved.

Both properties are described as

> **default-output-channel**
>
> If set, this attribute provides a reference to the channel, where Messages should be sent, if channel resolution fails to return any channels. If no default output channel is provided, the router will throw an Exception. If you would like to silently drop those messages instead, add the nullChannel as the default output channel attribute value.
>
> [Note]
>   A Message will only be sent to the default-output-channel if resolution-required is false and the channel is not resolved.
>
> **resolution-required**
>
> If true this attribute specifies that channel names must always be successfully resolved to channel instances that exist. If set to true, a MessagingException will be raised, in case the channel cannot be resolved. Setting this attribute to false, will cause any unresovable channels to be ignored. **This optional attribute will, if not explicitly set, default to true.**
>
> [Note]
>   A Message will only be sent to the default-output-channel, if specified, when resolution-required is false and the channel is not resolved.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the reply. as i mentioned "probably" wasn't not properly configured.

Comment: changed to `    public HeaderValueRouter router() {
        HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter(AGREEMENT_HEADER);
        router.setDefaultOutputChannel(defaultRouteChannel);
        router.setResolutionRequired(false);
        router.setChannelMapping("ENROLL", "enrollChannel");
        router.setChannelMapping("ENLIST", "enlistChannel");
        return router;
    }`  **all worked fine**.